# Flying Saucer - HTML to PDF and Licensing (iText)

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, pdfbox, flying-saucer

I'm writing code to convert HTML to PDF, which includes the following 2 dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-itext5</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have it working. And the only way I can see to do this is using the **ITextRenderer**. Unfortunately, it looks like this is iText 5, which requires AGPL license, or paying a large licensing fee.

Seems pretty clear to me, based on this license: https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/master/LICENSE

Is this correct?

Is there any other way to do this that doesn't require iText (or licensed software)?

I've tried Apache PDFBox, but it's so low-level, I'm not sure it would be possible. I know it wouldn't be easy. HTML -> PDF definitely isn't possible.

OpenPDF looked kinda weak.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

This is a somewhat small part of our project (startup), so licensed software isn't the first choice.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a licensing question, not a technical question.

Comment: Flying Saucer is a third party product that isn't endorsed by iText Group. iText has its own [HTML to PDF functionality](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml). It is correct that a commercial license is needed for closed source distribution of iText (AGPL). OpenPDF is a fork of the obselete iText 2 [and shouldn't be used in a commercial context](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) in spite of what its distributor claims. The license price of iText will be much less than the cost of development you'll need when using PDFBox.

Comment: What makes you say the license price for iText is large? Pricing of iText depends on your use of iText. A single server license costs about what you'd have to pay me if you'd hire me about 10 hours of work. Also: there are special conditions for startups who use iText in a SaaS context. We have given 100% reduction on the invoice of the first year. That means that you know the yearly price up-front, but you only have to start paying after 1 year (when we expect you already have some revenue).

Comment: You could try this https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/ it is on top of PDFBox.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks. I'll take a look. BTW, it says that it's based on a fork of Flying Saucer. Does that mean it may have the same iText licensing issues? Or is it completely independent of iText?

Comment: @yngwietiger I don't know. Look into the pom.xml or ask them.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr FYI, I was able to switch over to openhtmltopdf (from Flying Saucer) easily. Looks like it does everything I need it to do. BIG THANKS for the suggestion! (actually, I had looked at it briefly a few days ago, but had written it off for some reason). AIso, if you're curious, there are no references to iText (via "mvn dependency:tree | grep -i itext"), so it looks good there as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I knew about that project because one of the guys (Emmeran Seehuber) helped improve PDFBox / fix bug(s).

Comment: I am using the same as above and in one of the PDF page I am getting my content overlapped

Answer (score 19):

Edit: as pointed out in the comment, `org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf` uses OpenPDF now (2024). That replaces `org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf`.

---

As of today (2018), there are three implementations of Flying Saucer available, one of which is OpenPDF.

Quoting from their [readme](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) (emphasis mine):

> The available artifacts are:
>
> - org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-core - Core library and Java2D rendering
> - **org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf - PDF output using iText 2.x**
> - **org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf-itext5 - PDF output using iText 5.x**
> - **org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf - PDF output using OpenPDF**
> - org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-swt - SWT output
> - org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-log4j - Logging plugin for log4j
>
> **iText 2.x has unfixed security bugs. New projects should avoid it.**

OpenPDF and Flying Saucer itself are both licensed under LGPL. So you can use `flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf` now to avoid security issues with iText 2 and licensing issues with iText 5.

Comment: Update: org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf is now using OpenPDF